# four repeating letters check javascript, spam detection

Tags: javascript

Is there a a "smarter" way to do this? This works but I imagine has something to do with for loops, what if I was checking for 20 repeating  characters?

What happens if javascript is disabled?

Is there an easier way to check for "sensical" posts instead of say aldjfalkfja;lfjaklfjlkfj how would I filter that out without storing a library of words and comparing the string to those?

```
function counter(){
this.value = 0;
}

var count = new counter();

function updatecount(fnc){
fnc.value = count.value + 1;
}

function charbank1(){
this.value = "";
}

var cb1 = new charbank1();

function insertchar1(fnc){
fnc.value = cb1.value + String.fromCharCode(keynum);
}

function charbank2(){
this.value = "";
}

var cb2 = new charbank2();

function insertchar2(fnc){
fnc.value = cb2.value + String.fromCharCode(keynum);
}

function charbank3(){
this.value = "";
}

var cb3 = new charbank3();

function insertchar3(fnc){
fnc.value = cb3.value + String.fromCharCode(keynum);
}

function charbank4(){
this.value = "";
}

var cb4 = new charbank4();

function insertchar1(fnc){
fnc.value = cb4.value + String.fromCharCode(keynum);
}

function repeatingcharcheck(){

if(count.value < 4){

if(count.value == 1){
insertchar1(cb1);
}

if(count.value == 2){
insertchar2(cb2);
}

if(count.value == 3){
insertchar3(cb3);
}

if(count.value == 4){
insertchar4(cb4);
}

}else{
if(cb1.value == cb2.value == cb3.value == cb4.value){
alert('four letters in a row is not allowed');
window.location.replace('somewhere.com');
}
}

}
```

Comment: You can (and, probably, should) use regular expressions.

Comment: Four letters in a row can definitely happen in legitimate text, and your algorithm won't catch spam messages without four letters in a row. Instead, compute a "spam score" that takes into account, for example, capitalization and letter n-grams.